# How to read a html file with my webserver?

Tags: html, c, webserver, buffer

I would like to read my html file from my webserver, but i don't know how to do, i sought on the web for examples for see how do it work, but i found a lot of tutorials or he show how  to do it with a string array and not with a html file.
do you have any advice for me?
here my code :

```
int multiplex_server_event(int serv_sock) {
fd_set read_fd;
int maxFd, new_sock, ret;
int events[FD_SETSIZE];
int size = 1;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

events[0] = serv_sock;

while(1) {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    maxFd = events[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        FD_SET(events[i], &read_fd);
        if(maxFd < events[i]) {
            maxFd = events[i];
        }
    }
    ret = select(maxFd + 1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret <= 0) {
        error("select failed");
    }

    for(size_t i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        //si il y a bien le descripteur desc dans l'ensemble des descripteurs ens
        if(FD_ISSET(events[i], &read_fd)) {
            //si il y a rien à lire
            if(read(events[i], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0) { 
                close(events[i]);
                perror("read failed");
                //memset(events, 0, sizeof(events));
                events[i] = 0;
                size--;
            }
            printf("%s", buffer);
            //si il n'arrive pas à écrire dans le fichier
            if(write(events[i], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) == 0) {
                error("write failed");
            }
        }
    }

     //si il y a bien le premier descripteur desc dans l'ensemble des descripteurs ens
    if(FD_ISSET(events[0], &read_fd) != 0) {
        new_sock = accept(events[0], NULL, NULL);
        events[size] = new_sock;
        size++;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: It's not clear to me what part your code shows and what your actual question is. Is `multiplex_server_event` part of the server? Then it should be straight forward to use `fopen` and `fread` to open an html file on the server's local file system.

Comment: Can you give me examples of how to use them in this context?, multiplex_server_event is my function that i've created.